# hover fade out transition with mouse still on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

I can't figure out how to make a fade-in/fade-out effect on a div, without the mouse leaving the div.

I'll try to explain it better:

1. Mouse enters object
2. The object fades in
3. After a delay the object fades out, without the mouse leaving the area.

Comment: So you only want it to fade in if the mouse is on it?

Comment: I want it to fade out after some time (0.5-1s), without the mouse leaving.
I can do the fade-in part, with css transition, but i want the hover to fade out afer some time, even if the mouse is still on it.

Comment: Ah ok. You are looking for `delay` in jquery. Will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `mouseover` event then:

```
$(element).parent().mouseover(function() {
  $(element).fadeIn(1200).delay(1000).fadeOut(400);
});
```

1. You mouse over on the element, it fades in.
2. It waits for a second.
3. It fades out, even if you are on the element.

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $(".child").css("opacity", 0);
  $(".child").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 1000).delay(1000).animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```css
.parent {position: relative; background: #99f; height: 250px;}
.parent .child {position: absolute; top: 25%; left: 25%; width: 50%; height: 50%; background: #ccf;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <p>Stand on me?</p>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: But that's not what he wants, That will not fade out if the mouse stays on the div.

Comment: This is not what i need, sorry!

Comment: This will not fade out either... But a pure CSS solution.

Comment: I don't need it to flash ciclically.

Comment: No it doesn't. Have a look.

Comment: i see it flashing costantly as i keep my mouse on it

Comment: @FlavioMancuso I updated. Please run it to see how it works... `:)`

Comment: @FlavioMancuso Doesn't happen on mine! `:O`

Comment: if i put the mouse on the darker rectangle it only flash once, and it's good, but if i put the mouse on the lighter one it keeps flashing indefinitely

Comment: @FlavioMancuso Lemme fix it. But I am unable to replicate the issue. So I am doing it again. Give me a sec. I have already given `e.stopPropagation`, now will give `e.stopImmediatePropagation` too.

Comment: i don't think the problem is only mine, i'm running it in firefox and as i said before, if i place my cursor on the lighter rectangle it keeps flashing.

Comment: @FlavioMancuso I have totally changed the code. I am using Chrome. But now tested it on both the browsers. Have a look.

Comment: @PraveenKumar sorry for bothering you again, but i don't know why it doesn't work... http://jsfiddle.net/k9hd6hxe/

Comment: @FlavioMancuso This is because you have both CSS transitions and JavaScript open.

Comment: @PraveenKumar so i have to choose one of them and only use it?

Comment: @FlavioMancuso You did not load jQuery and blah blah... Check the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k9hd6hxe/1/

Comment: One of what buddy? @FlavioMancuso

Comment: @PraveenKumar i don't need to fade-in and out the image itself, but the hover on it.

Comment: @PraveenKumar look at this: http://quaaludeband.altervista.org/index3.html do you see the hovers on the images? About, Events, etc.
I need your script to affect these hovers.

Comment: @FlavioMancuso Those look like jQuery mouseovers and mouseouts.

Comment: They are CSS not jQuery, look under /* gestione dell'hover dei riquadri */

Answer (score 2):

For example you can do this in jquery:

`$('#id').fadeIn(1200).delay(1000).fadeOut(400);`

And if you want that on mouse on you could do this:

```
 $('#id').hover(function() {
          $('#id').fadeIn(1200).delay(1000).fadeOut(400);
        });
```

That might not be exactly what you want, but I'm sure you can figure it out from there.

Comment: @FlavioMancuso Was it what you wanted?

Comment: i'm trying to figure it out

Comment: please make a snippet, can't figure out how to implement this.

Comment: Can you provide your html?

Comment: Don't worry Manu, it seems that @Praveen Kumar solved my issue, thanks anyway!